# Access 2016 report missing fields with data between dates

Tags: date, ms-access, report, between

I want to create a report that summarizes data for the last 14 working days.  This means the report needs to exclude Saturdays and Sundays (and maybe holidays).

I am still working on how to do the above.  I believe it will be a vba solution.  But for now I have encountered another problem that I do not know how to solve.

My table has fields for a product, a quantity, and a date the entry was made (stored as "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn").

When I query my table for entries for the last 2 weeks I use the following expression in a query:

```
 Between DateAdd("d",1,Now()) And DateAdd("d",-14,Now())
```

If the date falls within the last 2 weeks and the time on a particular transaction is midnight i.e. 00:00, the query returns the product and the quantity. If the time is not midnight the query returns the product but the quantity field is blank.  It doesn't matter if I use date() or now().  It doesn't matter if I use an actual date such as:

```
 >=#11/24/2016#
```

So, the full query is:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tblWarehouseTransfer.Qty) AS SumOfQty
SELECT tblWarehouseTransfer.ProductID
FROM tblWarehouseTransfer
WHERE (((tblWarehouseTransfer.DateMoved) Between DateAdd("d",1,Now()) And    DateAdd("d",-14,Now())))
GROUP BY tblWarehouseTransfer.ProductID
ORDER BY tblWarehouseTransfer.ProductID
PIVOT (Date())-[datemoved]+1 In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
```

How can I get the product and quantity to show when the table field attributes include "hh:nn" and the time is other than 00:00?  I need the query to be dynamic so I need to use date() or now() not a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a work-around for my problem.  I have split the DateMoved field into 2, by creating a new field in the table that holds only the hours and minutes i.e. "Short Time". By entering data into the 'DateMoved' field as  DateValue(day()) i.e. "Short Date" the time is truncated.  Now the product and quantity fields show in the report and the query remains dynamic. The query SQL has not changed, just the manner in which the date is stored in the DateMoved field.